# Angular IFrame to same application route doesn't load the App

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

for my app, i would like to use an IFrame to show content from another route of the same application. For example:

- I Have a User Profile component, meant to be used to show a given user Profile. This would be the same component a normal user will see when it goes to "My Profile"
- For admin users, i have a User Browser component, that shows a table and when selecting a user, it should show the user profile in a sidebar/modal.

I would like to use an IFrame to show a route for the UserProfile component so i wouldn't have to bother in the implementation of input/output parameters and RBAC in the component (I Could just use the Guards already in place). Also, IFrame allows me to use the responsive version of the UserProfile Component as if it was in a small screen.

#### The Problem

When i try to use the IFrame, referencing a route in the application it shows a blank screen. Upon looking at the network requests, i see that the request was successful. And on a small test, i tried adding `<h1>Hello World</h1>` in my Angular index.html and the IFrame will load that, but not the actual route or the application at all.

The weird thing is that if i load the base route http://localhost:4200 it works. But routes like http://localhost:4200/whatever will not.

Also tried to use a built version of the app served by a http server, but still the application doesn't load in other routes apart from the home route. The route alone works, the issue is when it is loaded from an IFrame

I'm using Angular 17